# How to use empty disk spaces under /dev/sdb1 on Azure?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-storage, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VM with 200GB local SSD on Windows Azure.

When I want to use 100GB of it, a "Disk Quote Exceed Error" message is appeared. I can see that my home ( or root) directory is 30GB from the table below ( which is output of **`df -Th`** )

So how can I make the disk space /dev/sdb1 available to use in my home directory?

```
Filesystem    Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
------------------------------------------------------------
udev           devtmpfs  6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.4G  8.6M  1.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       30G  1.6G   28G   6% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      ext4      197G   60M  187G   1% /mnt
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: probably best to post this on serverfault or unix stackexchange. but you'd need to format/mount a disk to use it (and keep in mind, the temp disk is not *durable*).

Comment: I know it is temp @DavidMakogon but it just does not make sense for me, why Azure makes most of my 200GB storage place temporary?

Comment: Not sure what doesn't make sense. That temporary storage is essentially free, as part of the offering for VMs. And lots of apps and data engines take advantage of it. You always pay for durable storage (including OS disk). If you need a 128GB/512GB/1TB disk that's durable, just create one as an attached disk. Simple as that.

Comment: I see now. I never thought that way actually, I was thinking that place must be mine, and I must be able to use it anyway I want. I was mixing up the aim of Local SSD and Disk partition. So I first attached a disk as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/attach-disk  and then mounted it to my root as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/attach-disk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David Makogon said, the `/dev/sdb1` is **temporary disk**. This temporary disk must not be used to store data that you are not willing to lose. The temporary disk is present on the physical machine that is hosting your VM.  [image]

More information about Azure temporary disk, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/).

In your scenario, we can attach new disk to your VM, we can follow the link you mentioned in the comment.
[Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/attach-disk)
[Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/attach-disk)